# left: auto property of css does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I have a component in react.js app - tree table.

It looks like this in chrome or any other browser apart from IE - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndzH9.jpg

However, in IE11 - the same jss property makes it look like -https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9HjL.jpg

**Code Snippet for the checkbox: -**

```
"&$mainRoot":{
"& $root": {
        left: "auto",
        paddingLeft: "0.25rem",
        paddingRight: "0.75rem",

        "&>div": {
          top: "-0.0625rem"
        }
      }
}
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED?**

```
"&$mainRoot":{
"& $root": {
        left: "0rem",
        position: "absolute",
        paddingLeft: "0.25rem",
        paddingRight: "0.75rem",

        "&>div": {
          top: "-0.0625rem"
        }
      }
}
```

the changes in left and position - makes it look like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUxyc.jpg

**The position is correct, however, the actual look should be like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndzH9.jpg i.e. a stair-like effect for the tree table.**

**Another thing I tried was: -**

**changing the position to "relative" and adding property width: "100%" made it look like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/daDqz.jpg - thus, giving me the stair-like effect - however, not able to move it to more of the left side as left: "0rem"**

```
"&$mainRoot":{
"& $root": {
        left: "0rem",
        position: "relative",
        width: "100%",
        paddingLeft: "0.25rem",
        paddingRight: "0.75rem",

        "&>div": {
          top: "-0.0625rem"
        }
      }
}
```

Since the project is quite big and difficult for me to create a fiddle. I've created a sandbox if you want to play around - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-playground-mr4p6

My observations were that property - left: auto is not supported in IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that left: auto property was not working in IE11 only. It was working fine in all other browsers.

```
    root:{
    child1: {
     position: absolute;
     }
    child2: {
     left: auto;
     position: relative;
      }
    }
```

adding  **position: absolute to the adjacent child** made it work correctly in all browsers.

If anyone has any other points to add, please do.